# using git rebase -i

Tags: git, version-control

so I'm trying to split commits using the instructions in http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

try searching for "SPLITTING COMMITS"

there it says to "Mark the commit you want to split with the action "edit". "

how exactly do I do that

when I execute git rebase -i it opens a file

```
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out

...
```

how exactly do I execute those commands from that dialog

**EDIT**

So I managed to rebase successfully and committed to my local repo...

The problem is, when I try to push I get the error message:

```
 ! [rejected]        JJ-4322 -> JJ-4322 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'url.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

any ideas?

Comment: Above those lines is a list of commits.  Change the word in the first column.

Comment: You should get a list of commits, one per line. Prefix each line with the command you wish to use for that commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
rebase -i COMMIT
```

Will present you with a list of commits, you can change the default pick command with any in that list

```
pick 6d6da13 0000, liquibase, fixing build snafu's

# Rebase c56baf2..6d6da13 onto c56baf2
```

Becomes

```
edit 6d6da13 0000, liquibase, fixing build snafu's

# Rebase c56baf2..6d6da13 onto c56baf2
```

Edit:

Your 2nd question is because you are rewriting history and you have already pushed older versions that now conflict with your current state. You need to do:

```
git push --force YOURBRANCH
```

This will overwrite what is on the remote.